# Is it possible to post with Word 2007 via XML-RPC and limit categories by user?

Tags: categories, security, xml-rpc

I'm working on a project for a school district I work at where we want to use Word Press to have employees from all of the buildings post announcements and press releases via Word 2007.  We will then use RSS feeds to show the information on the district's web page and other subscribed locations.  The problem we are running into is when we create user roles for categories, this basically is not working through the XML-RPC in Word 2007.  It is working fine within the administration panel, but when the user goes to insert a category in Word, all of the categories are shown.  We would like to limit the available categories by user so that only a building secretay and principla can post the the high school category for example.   I have been search for a couple of weeks for a solution to this, if one exists.  Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Are you using a plugin to map roles to categories? If so which one? Otherwise post the code you're using to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

As per comment it is hard to answer this without knowing specifics of setup.

In general there are two generic approaches to this:

1. Prevent unwanted terms from being returned by filtering `get_terms_args` or other available hooks.
2. Prevent unwanted terms from being saved (or cancel them right after) by hooking somewhere in `wp_insert_post()`.

The more complex, but possibly much more flexible approach would be to extend `wp_xmlrpc_server` server class so that categories served by it are checked against user permissions.